# What is the purpose of using try, catch blocks?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

Is it a replacement for if, then blocks?  I have seen a lot of code where they are used like that.

Comment: They are used for exception handling. Some people do try to use try-catch blocks for control flow but that is really not good practice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not a replacement for an if, then block, it serves an entirely different purpose. The objective of a try, catch block is to try and do something which could fail and raise an exception (e.g., read a file from disk, but the file might not be there, etc.). After catching an exception, you can handle it.

```
try {
   riskyOperation();
catch (ExpectedException) {
   handleException();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of try catch blocks to allow you to *try* to perform and action and then if an exception occurs, *catch* the exception and deal with it gracefully rather than crashing.

Comment: But doesn't the IDE tell you what is the problem anyway?

Comment: @v.g. the IDE tells you about it, but it does not solve it. try & catch is probably the fastest way of telling you that you need to program some solution at a given line of code.

Answer (score 0):

A try block is the block of code in which exceptions occur.

A catch block catches and handles try block exceptions.